# create a dynamic ModalPopupExtender from code behind does not work

Tags: asp.net, dynamic, code-behind, modalpopupextender

I am trying to create a dynamic ModalPopupExtender from code behind that when i click on a button it pops a panel with a button in side.
i created a panel (named panel) with a button in side called ButtonOk (button.id ="ButtonOk")
but when i click the event handler of the first button (Button_Click) nothing happens please help me my code is:

```
protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HiddenField hf = new HiddenField();
    hf.ID = "hdnField";


    AjaxControlToolkit.ModalPopupExtender modalPop = new    AjaxControlToolkit.ModalPopupExtender();
    modalPop.ID = "ModalPopupExtenderSelectFilds";
    modalPop.PopupControlID =Convert.ToString(Page.FindControl(Convert.ToString(panel.ClientID))); //panel.ID;
    modalPop.TargetControlID = Convert.ToString(Page.FindControl(Convert.ToString(hf.ClientID))); //"hdnField";        
    modalPop.OkControlID = "ButtonOk";
    modalPop.BackgroundCssClass = "modalBackground";
    modalPop.BehaviorID = "modalPopupExtenderSelectFilds";

    modalPop.Show();
}
```

Comment: i think u have to add control's to that panel panel.controls.add() try this

Comment: Prabhavith is right, unless you add the control to the page it won't be rendered

Comment: in my panel i have checkbox controls ant the button ButtonOk how i now how can i add the panel to the page controls and do i need to to add the ModalPopupExtender  to the page controls?

Answer (score 0):

For help of other users, you will just have to add modalPop to area where control will be added to page

For example, this should be added at end of code

```
panel1.Controls.Add(modalPop);
```

Answer (score 0):

check this code to add controls to panel:-

this.panel1.Controls.Add(modalPop);

Answer (score 0):

In code behind, you can make this:

```
if (true)
{
var script = @"Sys.Application.add_load(function() { $find('behavoirIDModal').show(); });";
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "ShowPopup", script, true);
}
```

edit this: behavoirIDModal